# How to access Twitter Web Analytics?

Tags: twitter, analytics

Twitter Web Analytics was announced by Twitter back on September 13th of this year (see this post: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/introducing-twitter-web-analytics) and it was announced that it would be available to the general public in the following weeks after that.

It's now almost two months later, so it should be available for everyone now, in theory. Does anyone know how to access the new Twitter Web Analytics?  I don't see it in my Twitter account, is is available at a separate web address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it should be out by now.

In practice, its still in private beta, with no clear indication of when its actually coming out for broader public use.

Their [advertising page](https://business.twitter.com/advertise/analytics/) says its still only available to advertisers, and there haven't been any major subsequent announcements since that blog post indicating when it was actually going public.